# Problems with calling a method using an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I'm relevantly new to Java and just started my first semi serious assignment. I'm confident most of my code is working, the only problem is because I've been using classes I can't seem to call a method which uses an array into my main class. Every other method I want to call seems to work. I wonder if anyone has any explanation or easy solution to this?

Thanks in advance for taking time looking into, really appreciate it!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GeographyQuizMain 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        takeQuiz();
    }

    public static void takeQuiz(Question[][] questions)
    {

        int score = 0;
        RandomNumber randomQuestion = new RandomNumber();
        //user chooses catergory
        int cat = pickCatergory();
        //ask 10 questions
        for(int i = 0; i < 10;)
        {
            Scanner answerChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
            randomQuestion.dice();
            int q = (randomQuestion.dice() - 1);
            //checks to see if question as been asked before
            if (!questions[cat][q].beenAsked)
            {
                questions[cat][q].beenAsked = true; //changes question status to beenAsked
                System.out.println(questions[cat][q].promt);
                String answer = answerChoice.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\nYou picked: " + answer + "\nThe correct answer was: " + questions[cat][q].answer + "\n");

                if(answer.equals(questions[cat][q].answer))
                {
                    score++;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("That is the end of the quiz!\n"
                + "You got " + score + "/10");
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you have within your `Question` class

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the call itself,

This line `public static void takeQuiz(Question[][] questions)` states that the method will accept a two dimensional array ([][]) of an object named Question.
On the other hand, your call - `takeQuiz();` passes no array of such.

You should initialise an array of such to make this compile and pass it to the function. i.e.

`Question[][] questionArray = GenerateQuestionArray(); //you should write this method
takeQuiz(questionArray);`

Like you stated, it's clearly you're new to Java and I strongly suggest you to read the instructions and the information provided to you in class about that. I bet the details of Object initialisation, methods and arrays are covered there.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that problem with your method call, in your method  takeQuiz(); is taking 2 dimensional array for questions but at the calling time you are not providing that parameter so, compiler not able to found the method.
That's the problem.

try to use like this, this is simple an example for you. replace this with your actual values.

String[][] questions= new String[3][3];

takeQuiz(questions);

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have called your method `takeQuiz()` without actually supplying its arguments `Question[][] questions`